# jquery decode is not working properly

Tags: jquery

i have a string which contains some html entites and some html tags like this

```
var entity = '<strong>kjkkkjk<br><br><br></strong>&lt;iframe width="854" height="480" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/-FSjaaibpus" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""&gt;&lt;/iframe>';

var decode = $('<div></div>').html(entity).text();
console.log(decode);
```

it is giving this result which is not appropriate

```
kjkkkjk<iframe width="854" height="480" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/-FSjaaibpus" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
```

the desired result should be like this

```
<strong>kjkkkjk<br><br><br></strong><iframe width="854" height="480" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/-FSjaaibpus" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
```

where have i gone wrong ? how to get correct result ?

Comment: That's because parts of your string has been encoded twice - hence decoding it once isn't enough. I'd suggest you fix how the string is being encoded

Comment: php auto encodes iframe tags,

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd think that...? If you need further help we need to see the logic which is encoding your HTML string.

Comment: how to decode only html entites in a string using jquery, because if in a string there are like hello<br/>&lt;strong and decode this using jquery it removes the effect of <br/> tag. is there any solution if decoding using jquery do not remove effect of html tags which are not encoded.

Comment: You don't seem to be understanding the issue. Your logic to decode the string is correct and working. The problem is because you have somehow encoded parts of the string *twice*. You need to stop doing that. The issue is not with JS.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i have updated my question, now you can understand what is happening.

Comment: No, because you still haven't shown ***where*** the string is being encoded.

Comment: string is not encode anywhere, it is just an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use 'html' like this:

```
var entity = '<strong>kjkkkjk<br><br><br></strong>&lt;iframe width="854" height="480" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/-FSjaaibpus" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""&gt;&lt;/iframe>';

  var decode_text = $('<div></div>').html(entity).text();
  var decode_html = $('<div></div>').html(entity).html();
  console.log(decode_text);
  console.log(decode_html);
```